# Handle multiple onClick events jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a lot of `onClick` events. On a click of one element. I want to toggle hide or display classes (that hide / display) elements on the page when they're clicked.

It's working however, there's a lot of them and to me it just looks ugly.

```
$('.info_2').on('click', function() {
  $('#nav-wrapper').toggleClass('hidden_nav');
  $('#card-wrapper').toggleClass('centre_share');
  $('.E_info').toggleClass('display');
  $('#info-btn').css('opacity', '0');
  $('#nav-wrapper').delay(300).toggleClass('hidden');
  $('#nav-wrapper').removeClass('display_nav');
  $('#nav-wrapper').removeClass('display');
});

$('.info_back').on('click', function() {
  $('#nav-wrapper').removeClass('hidden_nav');
  $('#nav-wrapper').addClass('display_nav');
  $('#nav-wrapper').addClass('display');
  $('#info-btn').css('opacity', '1');
  $('#nav-wrapper').removeClass('hidden');
  $('.E_info').removeClass('display');
  $('.E_info').addClass('hidden');
  $('#card-wrapper').removeClass('centre_share');
});

$('#info-btn').on('click', function(){
  $('#info-btn').toggleClass('close_btn');
  $('.o-card_border').toggleClass('info_display card_active');
  $('.start_title').toggleClass('hidden remove_flow')
  $('#svg_full').attr('class', 'test');
  $('#svg_top').attr('class', 'test');
  $('#svg_bot').attr('class', 'test');
  $('#svg_bot_bot').attr('class', 'test');
  $('#svg_bot_right').attr('class', 'test');
  $('.rectangle_style_frame3 display').toggleClass('hidden');
  $('.triangle_style').toggleClass('hidden');

  $('.bg-info').toggleClass('display');
  $('.info_CharactersInvolved').toggleClass('display');
  $('.info_themes').toggleClass('display');
  $('.E_info').toggleClass('display');

});
```

Is there anyway to make code like this, that have a lot of one `onClick` event that toggle a lot of classes on other elements cleaner?

Thanks!

Comment: can you post the html with it, and make a js fiddle please?

Comment: Depending on your html structure, you could toggle a single class for each button (for example `info-2`) on the container and have the layout of the children being updated through css. `.info-2 #nav-wrapper { display: none; }`

Comment: I'd normally put the `html` in sorry @Enjoyted but it's Handlebars and quite a large file. In short, the `html` is just a few buttons, that has other items on the page that when I click, it hides them. I have a lot of these, like if I select an info button I want to hide 6, 7 class while i've got some information showing. But it looked very long and ugly

Comment: Any luck with this @DevJuniorThe50421st

Answer (score 2):

You can use commas to separate the ids or classes and use if statements to determine which id was clicked e.g:

```
$("#id1, #id2, id3, .class1, .class2, etc").on('click', function (e) {
    if(e.target.id == "id1") {
        // do id1 code
    }
    if($(e.target).hasClass('class1')) {
        // do class1 code
    }
    // repeat for other ids and classes
});
```

Comment: If you look into the event handlers of all the three elements, you'll find that there is hardly 1-2 statements common.

Comment: That's what the if statment is for. It can determine which id was actually clicked. This just puts all of the code into one click event

Comment: Ahh I never knew you could do this, thanks! Readability of my code, is this better or worse for what i'm doing? Having all my `onClick` events into one `onClick` event?

Comment: It would just tidy up some of the code. If you combine Tushar's answer with mine, it should tidy the code up considerably. I've also added code into my answer for doing this with classes instead of ids

Comment: Sweet! Thanks @NiallMitch14 appreciate it :) I'll mark as answered soon. I'll leave question up for a bit see if anyone else has a few suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: @NiallMitch14 The comparing class will not work when the element have more than one class, you can use `hasClass` or `is('.class1')` instead of that.

Comment: @Tushar that's right thanks. hasClass would be the proper way to do this. I'll edit my answer

Comment: Use `$(this)` instead of `$(event.target)`

Answer (score 1):

1. You can pass multiple classes to `removeClass`, `addClass` and `toggleClass`.
2. You can pass multiple selectors to `$()`. So, can combine same method calls on multiple selectors into one.
3. Different function calls on same selectors can be chained.

**Code:**

```
$('.info_2').on('click', function () {
    $('#nav-wrapper').toggleClass('hidden_nav').removeClass('display_nav display').delay(300).toggleClass('hidden');
    $('#card-wrapper').toggleClass('centre_share');
    $('.E_info').toggleClass('display');
    $('#info-btn').css('opacity', '0');
});

$('.info_back').on('click', function () {
    $('#nav-wrapper').removeClass('hidden_nav hidden centre_share').addClass('display_nav display');
    $('#info-btn').css('opacity', '1');
    $('.E_info').removeClass('display').addClass('hidden');
});

$('#info-btn').on('click', function () {
    $('#info-btn').toggleClass('close_btn');
    $('.o-card_border').toggleClass('info_display card_active');
    $('.start_title').toggleClass('hidden remove_flow')
    $('#svg_full, #svg_top, #svg_bot, #svg_bot_bot, #svg_bot_right').attr('class', 'test');
    $('rectangle_style_frame3 display, triangle_style').toggleClass('hidden');

    $('.bg-info, .info_CharactersInvolved, .info_themes, .E_info').toggleClass('display');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the bind() function of jquery;

The bind() method attaches one or more event handlers for selected elements, and specifies a function to run when the event occurs.

http://api.jquery.com/bind/

http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1371947&seqNum=3

Comment: OP knows how to bind event on element. And `bind` is deprecated since jQuery v1.7. Use `on` instead. This doesn't answer the question.